# repeat the clone action with the amount of items in my json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file, it gives me back some names what I wanna clone to my page, but everytime with a new name and a new div.

I have tried many things but can't get it to work.

Currently I have now:

```
var cloneTeam = $('.team').clone();
    for( var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        cloneTeam
            .appendTo('.team-catagory')
            .find('.team-name').text(teams[i].name);
    }
```

Comment: `.clone()` should be in that loop. Otherwise you just keep altering and appending the same dom element.

Comment: Aah ye, now it works but not really the way I wanna go it keeps repeating itself and keeps counting now my page is insane long. Need to find a small new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the item's jquery object, clone it each time you want to append it to the target place.

```js
var teams = [
  {name: 'a'},
  {name: 'b'},
  {name: 'c'},
  {name: 'd'},
];

// Get reference to the template.
// Only reference it at start.
var cloneTeam = $('.team');
var appendTarget = $('.team-category');
for( var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
  cloneTeam
   .clone()     // clone the template here.
   .appendTo('.team-catagory')
   .find('.team-name').text(teams[i].name);
}

// If you get its reference during or after the loop, 
// jquery will get all elements that have clase .team,
// which means element created before will now be included.
console.log(cloneTeam = $('.team'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tmpl' class='team'>
  <div class='team-name'></div>
</div>

<div class='team-catagory'></div>
```